# Failed to fetch csv file in Azure Datalake Storage using Python

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I ran into the following problem trying to read a csv file stored on a Datalake storage with Azure using python. I need to add that the Datalake has been privatised.
When running the program, i get this error message :  "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

the code is as follows :

```
service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="container_name")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("file_path")

# Test to check if the code can access the datalake
paths = file_system_client.get_paths(path="file_path")
for path in paths:
    print(path.name + '\n')



file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("Test_DataQuality.csv")

# line that failed
download = file_client.download_file()
```

I seem to be able to access the datalake as i can list files stored in the file_path's repository

There are barely any documentation on using Azure datalake storage with python reagrding this issue.
Please help !

I ve tryed using a different approach through pandas using

```
df = pandas.read_csv('abfs\[s\]://' + container_name + '/'+ file_path, storage_options = {'account_key' : storage_account_key})
```

but i get another error : "storage_options passed with file object or non-fsspec file path" which i do not quite get as it is literally the exemple given in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool)

Comment: where you are executing the above code?

Comment: Azure VMs with access rights to the datalake

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Ms_doc,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool) I reproduce same in my environment.

Make sure to check weather `fsspec` installed or not. If not, use below command to install `fsspec`.

```
pip install fsspec
```

**Follow below syntax :**

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file path>', storage_options = {'account_key' : 'Access_key'})
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, fsspec is already installed